# Embedding (Youtube/Vimeo) Videos on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: web, raspberry-pi3

I'm currently working with Raspberry Pi 3's to show webpages from our server, on site.
In this case, on site means about a 100 remote locations like grade schools, where we can't just walk in and update stuff (so making a site offline is a no-go, working with serviceworkers to cache is okay).

My problem is as followed:
When I try to show videos and/or images on the pages, the raspberry's browser eventually crashes.
Because the remote locations don't always have working internet and we do need to show something, we can't rely on refreshing every page.

We've tried both YouTube and Vimeo as video providers, but both crash eventually.

Can someone help or suggest some options?

Comment: What OS are you using on your RPi3?

Comment: Raspbian Jessie https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspbian-jessie-is-here/

Comment: How many images/videos are you trying to load?

Comment: 1 at a time, but about 5 overall. The site as some sort of page slider.

Comment: Using Firefox I suppose?

Comment: No, it's Chromium

Comment: Since what you are trying to accomplish is a Kiosk setup, I'd recommend looking into something like [Kweb](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=40860) instead.